# How to set language for user register page / form per subdomain

Tags: 7, forms, i18n-l10n

For a custom module, I need to change the language of the registration form based on the subdomain the user is currently active on.

I tried changing the global $language variable in hook_form_user_register_form_alter, but that does not work ($language variable is also not set at that point). I also tried setting the language in the $user object, but also no dice (probably because it is an anonymous user).

Finally I took a look at the [language negotiation api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!language.inc/group/language_negotiation/7), but setting up negotiation providers seems overkill for this (and haven't it studied enough to get a grasp on how to use it).

I just need to render the registration page in a different (but already available) language on /user/register, based on the subdomain. What would be the best way to achieve this.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how it's done in the [Domain Locale](https://drupal.org/project/domain_locale) module (thanks [Matt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8865/matt) for pointing it out), I am now using this in [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7):

```
if (strpos($cp, 'user/register') === 0 || strpos($cp, 'user/password') === 0 || strpos($cp, 'user/reset') === 0) {
    global $language;
    $lang = my_get_language_function();
    $languages = language_list();
    if (!empty($lang) && isset($languages[$lang]))
        $language = $languages[$lang];
    return;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! A little +1 on my answer would be appreciated though :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [the Domain Locale module](https://drupal.org/project/domain_locale). It allows you to change the available and default languages per domain.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I didn't really want to add another module for this and it seems they might override the user selected language (text is not very clear), but I took a look at their code which showed my how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding the question,  but if you go here:

`/admin/config/regional/language/configure`

You can set how languages are set (Determine the language from the URL (Path prefix or domain).

Domains can be configured here: 
`/admin/config/regional/language/edit/`

Comment: Good point! Totally forgot to check that. But it appears you can only define one domain per language and I need to specify more.